# How to strip down a jquery to fit your needs?

Tags: jquery, scripting, minimize, strip

I have this script running, and I'm wondering if I need all of http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

It's 70 kb, and I would love to be able to strip it down.

```
$('a.inframe').click(function() {
  var e=$(this);

  if (!e.data('state')) { //if state is undefined

   e.data('state','open'); //set the state to 'open'

   // Extract the frame height from the rel attribute
   var frameHeight=e.attr('rel');
   var pat1 = new RegExp('height:');
   pat1.test(frameHeight);
   frameHeight=RegExp.rightContext;
   var pat2 = new RegExp('px');
   pat2.test(frameHeight);
   frameHeight = RegExp.leftContext;
   if ( !frameHeight || (Math.ceil(frameHeight)!=Math.floor(frameHeight)) ) {
    //if it's null or not an integer
    frameHeight = '550'; //default frame height, in case none is specified
   };
   frameHeight += 'px';

   frameWidth = '100%';

   // Insert the iframe just after the link
   e.after('<iframe style="width:'+frameWidth+'; height:'+frameHeight+'; border:solid 0px #ccc; margin-bottom:1em; background:#fff;" src=' + e.attr('href') + ' frameborder="0" ></iframe>');
   var iframe=e.next('iframe');

   // Insert the "loading..." text
   iframe.before(' <small class="quiet"> hold on a sec...</small>')
   iframe.load(function(){ //once content was loaded
    iframe.slideDown(500); //slide it down
    iframe.prev('small').remove(); //remove the 'loading...'
   });
   e.attr('title','Hide'); //set the link title to 'Hide'
  }
  else if(e.data('state')=='closed') { //if state is 'closed'
   e.data('state', 'open');
   e.next('iframe').slideDown(500);
   e.attr('title','Hide');
  }
  else if(e.data('state')=='open') { //if state is 'open'
   e.data('state', 'closed');
   e.next('iframe').slideUp(500);
   e.attr('title','Show');
  }
  return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: You probably don't, but good luck weeding out the dependencies... :)

Comment: Yeah i think it's actually worth the 70k to not go through that pain

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input. too bad someone doesn't make an app that can pull all the dependencies out. I feel like that would be well used.

Comment: If you link to the jQuery library on one of the popular CDNs (like code.jquery.com), chances are the user will already have it in cache and won't even have to download it. But if even 70k are so important to you and you're only using a small subset of jQuery to begin with, you may be better off overall by writing straight Javascript and leave out jQuery completely.

Comment: It’s not only about the payload, it’s mainly because of subtile runtime conflicts that you might if you have other dependencies that internally depend on other versions of JQuery.